# Socket и bind

Tags: сокет, c++, visual-c++

Добрый день товарищи! Начал изучение C++, очень хочу сделать SMTP server, изучаю socket'ы/ Появилась проблема в коде :

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
//
using namespace std;
//
int main() {
    setlocale(0,"Rus");
    //
    SOCKET smtp_sock            =   socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //
    int iResult                 =   0; 
    //
    if (smtp_sock > 0) {
        cout << "Socket создан" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Socket не создан" << endl;
    }
    //
    sockaddr_in local_addr;
    //
    local_addr.sin_family       =   AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_port         =   htons(25);
    local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr  =   0;
    //
    if (bind(smtp_sock, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr))) {
        cout << "Связь socket'a с портом не выполнена";
        closesocket(smtp_sock);
    }
    //
    _getch();
    //
    if (smtp_sock> 0) {
        closesocket(smtp_sock);
    }
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Вылетает сообщение, **"Связь socket'a с портом не выполнена"**. **Помогите найти ошибку в коде и по возможности исправьте пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.**

И подскажите пожалуйста русский справочник по функциям **C++**, **msdn** сложен пока для меня.

Comment: А к другому порту (желательно после 1024) bind проходит? Может быть 25 порт занят (посмотреть `netstat -a`, или прав не хватает для доступа к привилегированному порту...

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но дело было в инициализации)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В винде Вам надо добавить перед

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

инициализацию сокетов

```
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
```

У Вас ее нет, поэтому ничего не работает.

А вообще, лучше все делайте в *nix.